# Dropping sql constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title says I'm trying to drop constraing and add a new one

What I'm trying to do through phpmyadmin sql query and I get wrong syntax error

```
ALTER TABLE items
DROP CONSTRAINT items_ibfk_1
```

And here is the constraint that is on that table

```
ALTER TABLE `items`
    ADD CONSTRAINT items_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (Patch_No) REFERENCES spells (Patch_No) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: The syntax error is the expected result. MySQL doesn't support `DROP CONSTRAINT` syntax. Valid syntax for the operation is `DROP FOREIGN KEY`.  (I'm guessing the questions you meant to ask was "Why is MySQL returning a syntax error?" and "What is the valid syntax to drop a foreign key constraint in MySQL?". But I'm just guessing. Maybe you didn't have a question.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE items DROP FOREIGN KEY items_ibfk_1;
```